# Android: multiple custom broadcastreceiver doesn't work

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

**I'm sorry if I have long problem here, but it took three days and I could not find a solution**

In my app I try to make some thing like whats app or messenger with the different that the user will send his text message to MySql DB on the server, and my customer service team will answer this message

here I have two situations will need it sometimes

**The first:** when the app have no connection or can't contact with server, the app will check connection and try to send the message every 1 minute.

**The second:** when user send a message successfully, the app will check if has been answered on the DB or not every 3 minutes.

because I'm very new with android
and because I can't use firebase because the high fees if my app will have many users!
I thinking about use service to launch Alarm with broadcastreceiver for every situation.

**Note:** the both situations never happen together. So, the services or Alarms will never works together.

If we haven't connection will launch the first and when its finished it's work will close and start the second. and if we have connection will start the second service only.

And I'll control on it by sharedPreferences entries with if statements in the activity
**like:** If sharedPreferences has value start the service if another value stop it

**the problem here...**
the first service and its alarm and receiver work successfully in the specified times I need

**but the second no**
The service only will start, but the alarm and reciever don't start

I don't know where the wrong I make

**this is manifest code:**

```
        <service
        android:name=".SECONDservice"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false"/>

        <service
        android:name=".FIRSTservice"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" />

        //This is my FIRST alarm (I changed the names to explain the example)
        <receiver
        android:name=".FIRSTalarm"
        android:process=":remote"/>

        <receiver
        android:name=".SECONDalarm"
        android:process=":remote"/>

        //This receiver to check if the phone reboot and the app need to start service again.
        <receiver android:name=".AlarmAutoStart">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

**This is the first service code:**

```
public class FIRSTservice extends Service {

FIRSTalarm FIRSTalarm = new FIRSTalarm();
    public void onCreate ()
    {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand (Intent intent,int flags, int startId)        {
        FIRSTalarm.setAlarm(this);
        return START_STICKY;
    ...
```

**The first Alarm code:**

```
public class FIRSTalarm extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,"MyAPP:mytag");

        wl.acquire();

        // My Check Connection code here


        wl.release();
    }

    public void setAlarm(Context context)
    {
        AlarmManager am =(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent i = new Intent(context, FIRSTalarm.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 60000, pi); // Millisec * Second * Minute
    }

    public void cancelAlarm(Context context)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, FIRSTalarm.class);
        PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.cancel(sender);
    }
}
```

**This is the second service code:**

```
public class SECONDservice extends Service {T

SECONDalarm SECONDalarm = new SECONDalarm();
    public void onCreate ()
    {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand (Intent intent,int flags, int startId)        {
        SECONDalarm.setAlarm(this);
        return START_STICKY;
    ...
```

**All of the above works successfully and at specified times**

**The problem in this Alarm (Doesn't work)**

**The Second alarm code**

```
public class SECONDalarm extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
    PowerManager pm2 = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl2 = pm2.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,"MyAPP:mytag2");

    wl2.acquire();

    // My code.
    Toast.makeText(context, "Second Alarm start?!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // For example


    wl2.release();
}

public void setAlarm(Context context)
{
    AlarmManager am2 =( AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent i2 = new Intent(context, SECONDalarm.class);
    PendingIntent pi2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1, i2, 0);
    am2.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 180000, pi2);
}

public void cancelAlarm(Context context)
{
    Intent intent3 = new Intent(context, SECONDalarm.class);
    PendingIntent sender3 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1, intent3, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager3 = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager3.cancel(sender3);
}
}
```

**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 0):

u can go for **workmanager** .U can use **PeriodicTimeWorkRequest** in work manager to achieve the work done repeteadly.
Workmanager will take all the actions in broadcast receiver,etc.Do dont need to maintain that.
Refer : [Work manager in android](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/basics)